# Kivy Scrollview: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, scrollview

Good Morning,

I'm new in this website but I constantly control topics that help me coding. I just started to learn coding and I'm new on python that i think it's one of the best.

By the way: I'm working on Kivy for build an app formed by cards that user can collect and consult. I built the cards (with MDCards) but the screen is blocked and if I add more than 5 cards they're invisible (out of screen). I'm trying to add a scrollview on the GridLayout in KV. Following some topic i found this way.

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button

KV = """
Screen:
    Controller:
        layout_content: layout_content
        BoxLayout:
            id: bl
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 10, 10
            row_default_height: '48dp'
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: 10, 10
            ScrollView:
                size: self.size
                GridLayout:
                    id: layout_content
                    size_hint_y: None
                    cols: 1
                    row_default_height: '20dp'
                    row_force_default: True
                    spacing: 0, 0
                    padding: 0, 0
                    
                    MDCard:
                        id: tel1
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        padding: "8dp"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: "180dp", "280dp"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Tele 1"
                            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                        MDSeparator:
                            height: "5dp"
                            width: "5dp"
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Descrizione del primo"
                    MDCard:
                        id: tel2
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        padding: "8dp"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: "180dp", "280dp"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Tele 2"
                            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                        MDSeparator:
                            height: "5dp"
                            width: "5dp"
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Descrizione del secondo"
                    MDCard:
                        id: tel2
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        padding: "8dp"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: "180dp", "280dp"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Tele 3"
                            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.texture_size[1]     
                        MDSeparator:
                            height: "5dp"
                            width: "5dp"
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Descrizione del terzo" 
                    MDCard:
                        id:tel4
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        padding: "8dp"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: "180dp", "280dp"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Telefilm 4"
                            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                        MDSeparator:
                            height: "5dp"
                            width: "5dp"
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Descrizione del quarto"
                    MDCard:
                        id:tel5
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        padding: "8dp"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: "180dp", "280dp"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Tele 5"
                            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                        MDSeparator:
                            height: "5dp"
                            width: "5dp"
                        MDLabel: 
                            text: "Descrizione del quinto"                 
"""

class Controller(FloatLayout):
    layout_content = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout_content.bind(minimum_height=self.layout_content.setter('height'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "LukeFlix"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

MainApp().run()
```

But I get this Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3APP/main.py", line 140, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3APP\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3APP\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3APP/main.py", line 132, in build
     return Builder.load_string(KV)
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3APP\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 408, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3APP\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3APP/main.py", line 125, in __init__
     self.layout_content.bind(minimum_height=self.layout_content.setter('height'))
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the `__init__()` method of the `Controller` class. At that point, the `layout_content` property has not yet been assigned. You can eliminate that `__init__()` method by redefining `Controller` like this:

```
class Controller(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

And then accomplish the same desired result by modifying the `ScrollView` section of your `kv`:

```
        ScrollView:
            # size: self.size   # this has no effect
            GridLayout:
                id: layout_content
                size_hint_y: None
                cols: 1
                # row_default_height: '20dp'
                # row_force_default: True
                height: self.minimum_height
                spacing: 0, 0
                padding: 0, 0
```

Note the `height: self.minimum_height` line, which does what your `__init__()` method was trying to do. Also, the row defaults were forcing the rows in the `GridLayout` to a too small height.

Comment: Great @John Anderson. It worked and I understand it all. I thank you so much!